# Failed downloading chromedriver v121.0.6167.184: Download failed: server returned code 404. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chromium, webdriver-io

Failed downloading chromedriver v121.0.6167.184: Download failed: server returned code 404. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.184/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip, retrying ...

Facing issues with WebdriverIO

Unable to download chrome for automation

"devDependencies": {
"@alfonso-presa/soft-assert": "^0.6.0",
"@wdio/cli": "^8.21.0",
"@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.21.0",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^8.21.0",
"@wdio/sauce-service": "^8.23.0",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.21.0",
"axios": "^1.6.4",
"chai": "^4.3.10",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^7.1.1",
"dotenv": "^16.3.1",
"fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
"multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.5.0",
"n-readlines": "^1.0.1",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"wdio-cucumber-reporter": "^0.0.2",
"wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^5.1.8"
},

Answer (score 5):

Apparently they changed the urls
eg: this https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.184/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
to
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.184/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
in my case for linux
check here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
maybe for js you can temporarily fix it by doing: `npm i chromedriver`

Comment: Yes, Noticed the same change. So How can I get this updated for my Wdio code to refer correct repo to download. I am using Windows env.

Comment: I ran it again, and it worked for me without making any changes, XD

Comment: I tried to copy the chromedriver.exe file in the node_modules folder. Still did not work. For some reason WDIO, v8 makes and attempt to get the driver from that site. How to stop this action? services: [
    //     ['chromedriver', {
    //         chromedriverCustomPath: './node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
    //     }
    //     ],
    // ],

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I had to change line 283 in seleniumwire's patcher.py to use this new URL base (in my local venv anyway). It's better than what I was doing a few hours ago (overriding the version to use 121.0.6167.85 instead of 121.0.6167.184 to patch the linux executable).

Comment: In my last comment, I was stating that I had to modify patcher.py. I mistakenly said it was in seleniumwire. It was not. patcher.py is part of undetected_chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your `@wdio` packes should fix it.

A workaround was merged https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/pull/12305
And they released a fix `webdriver v8.32.2` https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v8.32.2

Answer (score 1):

Error: Error: Failed downloading chromedriver v121.0.6167.184: Download failed:
server returned code 404. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.184/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip, retrying ...

To solve this issue run below two commands

1. npm update
2. npm install --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an older Rails app when deploying to Circle CI.  I was using this orb in my .circleci/config.yml file:

`browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.6`

Updating this to:

`browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.7`

took care of the problem for my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WDIO v8.14 or above you can specify the chrome version, allowing you to workaround missing drivers. As well as pin the chrome version (for when you need repeatable builds).

WDIO will automatically download both chrome and the matching chromedriver.

See [docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/driverbinaries#customizing-the-level-of-automation) for more details

**snippet from package.json**

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.31.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.31.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.31.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.31.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
```

**snippet from wdio.conf.ts**

```js
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "chrome",
      browserVersion: "120",
    },
  ],
```